# D3 leaves wrong elements on screen

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My d3 selection starts with a large dataset, appending a circle to my SVG for each element in it and setting the ID of the circle element to match the ID of the data item it represents.

Then, I call `.data()` on that same selection, passing in a smaller subset of the original. As expected, the number of circles on the screen after I do so matches the number of items in the smaller dataset. However, when I inspect the elements on the screen, their IDs do not match the IDs of the items in the new dataset.

Why might this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass a key function to data, the data is associated to existing elements via their position.

You probably want something like

```
.data(data, function(d) { return d.id; });
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data):

> To control how data is joined to elements, a key function may be specified. This replaces the default by-index behavior; the key function is invoked once for each element in the new data array, and once again for each existing element in the selection.

Comment: aha! I knew it had something to do with key functions, but I hadn't quite wrapped my head around those. That made it click. Thanks, will accept when it lets me. (p.s. it worked beautifully)